# Acessar atributos do tipo Object

Tags: java, fila

Estou com dificuldades em acessar valores de um atributo do tipo Object. Tenho uma classe No que tem como atributos No prox, e Object Item.

Cada item é um objeto da classe Assunto.

Enfileiro os itens da classe No normalmente, entretanto quando tento imprimir, consigo apenas o objeto item como retorno... Como faço para adentrar o tipo Object (item) e ter acesso aos atributos do Assunto?

Esse código e responsavel pela impressão:

```
public void imprime() {
    System.out.println(size);
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    System.out.println("Desc:"+ head.item);
        head = head.getProximo();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Se itens são sempre Assuntos, por que você não declara como Assunto e não como Object?

De qualquer forma, se você não quiser/puder mudar isso, pra acessar os atributos de Assunto, você precisa fazer um cast, assim o java vai tentar converter o objeto para o tipo que você quer, você faz isso informando o tipo entre parênteses.

```
System.out.println("Desc:"+ ((Assunto)head.item).propriedadeDeAssunto);
```

Outra dica, não é uma boa prática acessar propriedades diretamente, ao invés disso, torne as propriedades privadas e crie métodos get e set para acessar os valores, assim você mantém o encapsulamento. Se você ainda está estudando e não viu isso, você vai ver no futuro.